# Justification of hebrew - Minipage and wrapfig

Tags: minipage, hebrew, wrapfig, octavo

I'm using the minipage and wrapfig options to have text wrapping around a few words. I'm not able to properly justify Hebrew. It should be ragged right.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{octavo}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
%layoutsize={110mm, 180mm},
%layoutoffset={5mm, 10mm},
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=10.5cm,
inner=2.5cm,
%marginparwidth=20pt,
    ]
    {geometry}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}%%% 

%MULTIPLE COLUMNS
\usepackage{paracol}
\twosided
\footnotelayout{m}
\columnsep=0.05\textwidth
\columnratio{0.5}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}

\begin{document}


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{minipage}{0.27\linewidth} 
 {\fontsize{46pt}{46pt}\selectfont \vspace{3pt} \texthebrew{אלה} \vspace{1pt}
 \noindent
 \texthebrew{הדברים}}
 \vspace{5pt}
    \end{minipage}\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you have a minpage in the wrapfig? the wrapfig  .4 textwidth and the minipage then restricts to .108 textwidth so you have  tiny space and use a massive 46pt font???

Comment: your vspace will come _after_ the text and `\noindent` does nothing as it is not at the start of a paragraph, it is always best to put a blank line before `\vspace`

Comment: Yes you are right. No need of minipage. I enclosed the hebrew text in a \flushlight environment and it works. And thanks for the \vspace advice. Well appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestions of @DavidCarlisle and using `\selectlanguage{hebrew}` instead then `\texthebrew{}`

```
\documentclass[14pt]{octavo}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{fontsize}
\usepackage[
paperwidth=160mm, paperheight=240mm,
%layoutsize={110mm, 180mm},
%layoutoffset={5mm, 10mm},
textheight=18cm,
textwidth=10.5cm,
inner=2.5cm,
%marginparwidth=20pt,
    ]
    {geometry}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}%%% 

%MULTIPLE COLUMNS
\usepackage{paracol}
\twosided
\footnotelayout{m}
\columnsep=0.05\textwidth
\columnratio{0.5}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\setdefaultlanguage{italian}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{New Peninim MT}

\begin{document}


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.4\textwidth}
   \selectlanguage{hebrew}
\begin{flushright}
 {\fontsize{46pt}{46pt}\selectfont אלה \\ הדברים
}
\end{flushright}
 \vspace{5pt}
   \end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}
```